# I want BLE broadcast in android smart phone

Tags: android, broadcast, ibeacon

I'll buy beacon having ibeacon technology(ex. estimote)

Before getting, I want to test.

I have android 4.3 and bluetooth 4.0.

I want to broadcast beacon signal in my phone.

So, other phone download ble scanner app and start ble scanner.

But, not scan my phone....

what's problem?

Comment: what do want exactly?. Do you want make your as ble device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test with two phones, you need one phone to be an iBeacon transmitter.  This is currently only possible on Android Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 devices running Android 5.0, as well as with iOS devices running iOS 7+.

If you have one of these devices, I would suggest turning it into a beacon transmitter using my [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) app for iOS or [QuickBeacon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.quickbeacon&hl=en) for Android.  On the second receiving phone you can then detect the beacon use the Locate app for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) or [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8).

Before trying this, make sure one of your two phones supports transmitting as a beacon.